# Check Constraints in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, union

We have a bunch of tables in Microsoft SQL so that each table has its own check constraint. At the end we have created a partition view that does a "UNION ALL" against these tables. Our attempts to insert into this partition view is quite successful. Select, update and delete all work properly.

We want a similar functionality in MySQL 5.4 too. Is this feasible to create such a structure at all? If yes, where can I find further information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want MySQL's [merge storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/merge-storage-engine.html).